# Write text with coefficient like C₁, C₂, C₃ on label

Tags: c#, label

I have to write text with coefficient value like C<sub>1</sub>, C<sub>2</sub>, C<sub>3</sub> on label text, so please tell me how can i write ???

thanks
Shashi Jaiswal

Comment: Winform, WebForm, WPF?

Comment: Does `label1.Text = "C₁";` not work?

Answer (score 7):

You need a font that comes with glyphs for Unicode codepoints [U+2080](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2080/index.htm) to [U+2089](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2089/index.htm):

```
label1.Font = new Font("DejaVu Sans", 10);
label1.Text = "C₁";  // or "C\u2081"
```

*(assuming WinForms)*

Answer (score 3):

In WinForms you need to emulate that with a `RichTextBox`

```
// Appearance as a label
var subscriptFont = new System.Drawing.Font(
                        richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, 
                        richTextBox1.Font.Size - 2);
richTextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
richTextBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
richTextBox1.Text = "C1, C2, C3";
// subscript 1
richTextBox1.Select(1, 1);
richTextBox1.SelectionCharOffset = -3;
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = subscriptFont;
// subscript 2
richTextBox1.Select(5, 1);
richTextBox1.SelectionCharOffset = -3;
richTextBox1.SelectionFont =subscriptFont;
// subscript 3
richTextBox1.Select(9, 1);
richTextBox1.SelectionCharOffset = -3;
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = subscriptFont;
subscriptFont.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a different font that haves subindexes...

Comment: But you can't use a weird font if you're creating a web application (your users won't have it).

Comment: @kappa: In that case you can use HTML's `<sub>` tag.

Answer (score -3):

You can't. Plain and simple.

(But you could use two labels, positioned and sized accordingly, or use a label that supports complex markup... Or use UTF-8, which allows them...)

But a stock C# Winforms project? Nah.

Comment: The `.Text` supports UTF16 as do all string operations. It's the font that's the limitation.