# Is there a way to preserve text formatting in Excel when extracting it from the worksheet with C# and storing the values into strings?

Tags: c#, string, excel, text-formatting

### What I'm Trying to Do:

I am reading in cell values in an Excel worksheet, and the text often has special formatting such as superscript and subscript.  I would like to preserve this formatting when bringing it into my C# application, using the strings for various labels and such.  However, with my current implementation, all superscript and subscript characters lose that formatting.  I believe it has to do with the fact that I cast things to different types throughout the process:

```
        const string fileName = "C:\\Users\\J.Smith\\Desktop\\FeatureInfoPropertyAttributesEXCEL.xlsx";

        // Prepare the required items
        Workbook wb = null;

        // Start Excel
        Application excel = new Application {Visible = false};

        try
        {
            // Open file
            Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName);

            // Read sheets
            Sheets sheets = wb.Worksheets;

            // Select sheet
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet) sheets.Item["FeatureInfoPropertyAttributes"];

            string firstCellForPropertiesRange = "A2";
            string secondCellForPropertiesRange = ws.Range[firstCellForPropertiesRange].End[XlDirection.xlDown].Address;
            string firstCellForHeadersRange = firstCellForPropertiesRange.Replace("A", "B");
            string secondCellForHeadersRange = secondCellForPropertiesRange.Replace("A", "B");
            string firstCellForProposedHeadersRange1 = firstCellForHeadersRange.Replace("B", "C");
            string secondCellForProposedHeadersRange1 = secondCellForHeadersRange.Replace("B", "C");
            string firstCellForProposedHeadersRange2 = firstCellForProposedHeadersRange1.Replace("C", "D");
            string secondCellForProposedHeadersRange2 = secondCellForProposedHeadersRange1.Replace("C", "D");

            Range propertiesRange = ws.Range[firstCellForPropertiesRange, secondCellForPropertiesRange];
            Range headersRange = ws.Range[firstCellForHeadersRange, secondCellForHeadersRange];
            Range proposedHeadersRange1 = ws.Range[firstCellForProposedHeadersRange1, secondCellForProposedHeadersRange1];
            Range proposedHeadersRange2 =
                ws.Range[firstCellForProposedHeadersRange2, secondCellForProposedHeadersRange2];

            List<string> properties =
                propertiesRange.Cells.Cast<object>()
                               .Select((t, i) => ((Range) propertiesRange.Cells[i + 1]).Value2 ?? string.Empty)
                               .Cast<string>()
                               .ToList();
            List<string> existingHeaders =
                headersRange.Cells.Cast<object>()
                            .Select((t, i) => ((Range) headersRange.Cells[i + 1]).Value2 ?? string.Empty)
                            .Cast<string>()
                            .ToList();

            List<string> proposedHeaders1 =
                proposedHeadersRange1.Cells.Cast<object>()
                                     .Select(
                                         (t, i) =>
                                         ((Range) proposedHeadersRange1.Cells[i + 1]).Value2 ?? string.Empty)
                                     .Cast<string>()
                                     .ToList();

            List<string> proposedHeaders2 =
                proposedHeadersRange2.Cells.Cast<object>()
                                     .Select(
                                         (t, i) =>
                                         ((Range)proposedHeadersRange2.Cells[i + 1]).Value2 ?? string.Empty)
                                     .Cast<string>()
                                     .ToList();

            foreach (string s in proposedHeaders1.Where(s => !s.Equals(string.Empty)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            foreach (string s in proposedHeaders2.Where(s => !s.Equals(string.Empty)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            excel.Visible = true;
            wb.Close(false, null, null);
            excel.Quit();
        }
```

### First Question:

Does C# strings support such formatting characteristics as superscript and subscript in strings?

### Second Question:

If the answer to the first question is 'yes', how would I go about accomplishing this?

### Update: Example of a hard coded string with superscript formatting

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the superscript/subscript information from Excel via the logical flags in the `Font Property` of the given `Range`:

```
Range curRange = ws.get_Range("A1");
if(curRange.Font.Superscript)
{
    //It is a superscript
}
if(curRange.Font.Subscript)
{
    //It is a subscript
}
```

The easiest way to represent this in C# winforms is relying on a `RichTextBox` (you can even make it "look like a label", as suggested in the following link) and on its `SelectionCharOffset`. With `Labels`, it is not so straightforward but there are some [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220046/write-text-with-coefficient-like-c-c-c-on-label).

---------- UPDATE

ANSWER TO THE FIRST QUESTION:

C# supports formatting through its `Objects`, not its `string type`. `Excel strings` do not support formatting either; the `Ranges` are the ones in charge of dealing with this.

ANSWER TO THE SECOND QUESTION:

You can replicate in C# what Excel `Cells`/`Ranges` do by relying on the corresponding C# equivalent, that is: `Controls`/`Objects`. The `Control` meant for text-decoration is the `RichTextBox` and thus it is the best equivalent in this case. Nonetheless, there are different ways to deliver the result you want by using other `Controls`, as explained above.

Comment: Thanks @varocarbas, I appreciate your help :)  So, to clarify, the C# string type is not capable of superscript and subscript formatting (if I were to print out to output as these lists are getting built), but I would be able to record the characters that WERE superscript and subscript and re-apply that formatting to the text once they are in a RichTextBox?  Also, I currently display this text in the Cells of a DevExpress GridView.  Once I get to that point, I'd like to see if RichTextBox's can be used for those cells.  But for now, off the top of your head, do you know if this is supported?

Comment: @JakeSmith Quick answer to your first question: yes; more detailed answer in my next comment. Regarding if the gridView supports this formatting, you might apply the same ideas than for labels in the link I posted (i.e., rely on specific fonts and write the subscripts/superscripts directly); also you have the option to change the gridview such that  a Richtextbox is included on it; on top of all that you have the formatting options of the gridview itself which might account for that (no idea, to be honest).

Comment: @JakeSmith regarding your first statement, note that Excel strings are not capable of any kind of formatting neither. String is a type of data including just characters. Excel accounts for formating through "Ranges" and, externally, Cells. The equivalent in C# to Ranges are the different types of Objects, whose external representation are the Controls you put in a Form; one of these Controls (the one precisely meant for this kind of things) is the RichTextBox. Thus a more proper answer to your first question is: both Excel and C# support formatting although not in their string types.

Comment: @JakeSmith proper answer in a summarised form: Richtextboxes (or Labels or cells in Datagrids, etc.) are the C# equivalent to Cells in Excel (which are the ones actually recognising the subscripts/superscripts) :)

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the great explanations.  The reason I asked about the string type is that for one of our labels that I can think of, we set the text of it explicitly with a hard coded string that we copied and pasted from Word, which had "TM" included with superscript format.  Visual Studio allowed us to paste this in as a string and kept the format, and it appears this way in the label.  Is this not an example of the string type supporting this formatting, but an example of something else implicitly handling this formatting for me behind the scenes then?

Comment: @JakeSmith what you describe is stored in the Label (a Control) not in a string. The link I included in my answer talks about that: you can write special characters in a Label (to not be mixed-up with a string, that is what you use to declare variables in the code) by making sure that the given Font is of certain type: read the link I included; but remember that it refers to Labels; DataDrids MIGHT behave equivalently but don't have to (testing is the best way to know).

Comment: Check out the picture I added to my question, this is the string that I'm talking about.

Comment: @JakeSmith I have answered to you in my last comment: the string does not have formatting, the Label has. Please visit the link I posted in my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220046/write-text-with-coefficient-like-c-c-c-on-label), see the second answer, he talks about that. Exactly the same than a RichTextBox can support lots of differents formats, a Label can support some and, perhaps, a  GridView a few; but all this are Controls (the equivalent to Cells, as explained).

Comment: @JakeSmith to understand this point better: if you change the Font of the Label you are posting in this picture to one which does not support this special character, it would stop showing it. The string type is one of the things which the given Control brings into consideration when displaying anything and it only stores characters; this together with the encoding/font-type is what displays what you finally see. There is no single location storing all this information, you associate what you see with "string" (the characters) because is the most evident thing, but this is not the reality.

Comment: I was wondering if you were stilling willing to look a little deeper into this one.  As part of this process, I am also writing the text out to a .cs file, adding attributes to public properties for these cell values.  Would you know what objects I would need to use in order to write a text file (with extension .cs) that would have attributes like: `[Description("Blah blah B4")]` where the 4 is has subscript format?  The RichTextBox controls currently get there values from these attributes if they exist, so I would like to see if the formatted text could live in the attributes...

Comment: @JakeSmith I hope that you will understand that this has nothing to do with the original question and thus you should post a new one. Additionally, I am not completely sure that I do understand your question; if you mean how can transfer formatting like subscripts to external files, the answer: it depends upon the external support. For example a normal text file does not support subscripts (or do it under very specific conditions), Word supports without any problem... the key here is not the source (C#) but the destination (you would have to apply its rules). In any case, new question, please.